# PHP - Achieve certain syntax with multiple classes

Tags: php, syntax, scope, resolution, operator-keyword

(PHP7) I have two classes but would like to access one class inside of another for example:

```
Syntax: Property::House()->getAddress();

class Property
{
  protected $House;
  function Property()
  {
    self::$House = new House();
  }

  public function House()
  {
     return self::$House;
  }
}
class House
{
  public function getAddress()
  {
     // code
  }
}
```

does anyone know to accomplish this?, the syntax needs to be the same but the classes can change if needed

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I have a feeling that there's a better way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to achieve. Perhaps you're asking the wrong question. What is it exactly that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property Property::$House

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your class setup is going to give you deprecation errors in PHP7. You'd be better off using the __construct() method in place of Property() if you're wanting to use non-static calls.

Secondly. Are you sure you don't want House to extend the Property class instead of being a property of the Property class?

Thirdly, assuming you're sure of what you're trying to achieve this should work...

```
<?php
    class Property
    { 

        static function House()
        {
            return new House();
        }
    }

    class House
    {
        public function getAddress()
        {
            echo 'YAY!';
        }
    }

    Property::House()->getAddress();
```

Comment: wouldn't that reset the House class everytime I call it? as its returning a new empty House class each time

Comment: JezEmerys code was just an example of how to set up the classes. If you want to 'keep' the house in the property instead of creating a new one every time, assign it to a variable.
$this->house = new House();

Comment: @ChrisH Do you want it not to reset every time you call the static function?

Comment: @Perumal93 no, I need the house class to be created at the start of the script and then during runtime have values attached to variables inside the class etc which I can reuse and call throughout runtime, if that makes sense

Comment: @ChrisH Can you please explain more precisely? By the way, I've edited the answer to make you clear. JezEmery doesn't yet approve the edit. I think once it is approved, you may get your solution.

Comment: You said you need to reuse them throughout runtime after the `House` class object is instantiated. You then need to instantiate the object and attach it to `$GLOBALS` superglobal array. For example, `$GLOBALS['house_obj'] = new House();`. Doing such, you can access the object through all the pages. Hope you got it.